# Git commit and Push fails if there is nothing to commit

Tags: git, powershell, jenkins

I have a Project in Jenkins where I have to checkout for different repositories and update the versions of three-component say c1,c2,c3 in Pom files of Projects checked out, not all projects require all three versions to be updated some projects has all three versions and some have two of them and some have only one. after a successful update of POM files, the pom files needs to be committed and pushed back to the Master or some other branch, I have written a PowerShell script that does this but the Jenkins job is failing when there is nothing to commit. I can try to use

```
git diff --quiet && git diff --staged --quiet || git commit -am 'some message'
```

The problem is that i have a single script which goes inside each project and does this

```
git add pom.xml
git commit -m "message"
if ($? -ne $True) {
   write-host  "Error running command 'git commit''"
   exit ..

git push origin 
if ($? -ne $True) {
   write-host  "Error running command 'git push''"
   exit ..
```

Now the problem is that it could happen that out of C1, C2 and C3 only one of them changed or two of them changed so if the condition is not met in the first stage of script it will exit and skip other valid git commit and pushes and it will also exit if there is nothing to commit because version of C1 or C2 or C3 not changed and there is nothing to commit , Please can someone suggest a better way to handle this.

Already tried

```
git diff --quiet && git diff --staged --quiet || git commit -am ' message'

git add pom.xml
git commit -m "message"
if ($? -ne $True) {
   write-host  "Error running command 'git commit''"
   exit 1
}

git push origin $Branch
if ($? -ne $True) {
   write-host  "Error running command 'git push''"
   exit 2
}
write-host "git push origin $Branch exited successfully"
cd ..
exit 0
```

I would like this Big job to succeeds, although I can also divide the job into 4 parallel jobs I would still like to know

1. how can make the job successful even though there is nothing to commit
2. when I am using a command like this in Powershell it is failing git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||git commit -m "Jenkins automatic update commit", any pointers how it will correctly pass in PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first point, you have the [`--allow-empty` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---allow-empty) for commit, which does just that.